# Flutter: pub finished with exit code 255

Tags: flutter, serialization, model, dart-pub, jsonmodel

I am making models for my flutter application via build runner,json model and json serializable. But i got this error

```
Unhandled exception:
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
#0      _StringBase.[] (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:247:55)
#1      changeFirstChar (file:///C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/json_model-0.0.2/bin/json_model.dart:89:41)
#2      getType (file:///C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/json_model-0.0.2/bin/json_model.dart:116:20)
#3      walk.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (file:///C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/json_model-0.0.2/bin/json_model.dart:62:23)
#4      _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:379:8)
#5      walk.<anonymous closure> (file:///C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/json_model-0.0.2/bin/json_model.dart:50:37)
#6      List.forEach (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:282:8)
#7      walk (file:///C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/json_model-0.0.2/bin/json_model.dart:38:8)
#8      main (file:///C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/json_model-0.0.2/bin/json_model.dart:18:6)
#9      _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:299:32)
#10     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)
pub finished with exit code 255
```

In my pubspec.yaml file i added these flutter packages in dev dependencies:

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  json_model: ^0.0.2
  json_serializable:
  build_runner:
```

My Json files for which i want to make models:

**1st json file**

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "country": "Australia",
  "currencySymbol": "$"
}
```

**2nd Json file**

```
{
  "currencylist": "$[]currency"
}
```

Can you please help me where i am doing wrong in this and why i am getting this error when i run command in terminal 
**flutter packages pub run json_model**.

Answer (score 8):

this is too late but someone might get use of it, this worked for me:

I think this might happen when you change something in your model and you run agin

```
flutter pub run build_runner build
```

update:

run this and it will do the job for you:

```
flutter pub run build_runner build  --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

old : so first try to delete all generated files that ends with

> XXX.g.dart

and run

```
flutter clean
```

then

```
flutter pub get
```

Finally

```
flutter pub run build_runner build
```

Comment: I spent an hour and this is the solution worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: @Dennis you might run this one and it will do the job for you 
`flutter pub run build_runner build  --delete-conflicting-outputs`

Comment: I always use --delete-conflicting-outputs command to save time instead of running build_runner again after it instructs. But I never faced the problem with error code 255 before. So manually deleting the .g files worked. Weird. 

Comment: Glad to hear every thing is working fine for you, keep the good work @Dennis   

Comment: flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs -- It still failing for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can simple run the

```
1.flutter clean.
2.flutter pub get.
```

This saves my several hours.

Answer (score 0):

Check your pubspec.yaml file.

dependencies:

```
  json_annotation: ^2.0.0
```

dev_dependencies:

```
  json_model: //it is required to add for your error
  build_runner: ^1.0.0
  json_serializable: ^2.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be easier than it seems. It may tell you an authentication error that refers to the "certificate_password" in "msix_config".

Being a data that is not recommended to push or register, it may be overlooked to place the correct data of the certificate in case you are using it.

[image]