# Successfully generated launcher icons Unhandled exception: FormatException: Invalid number (at character 1)

Tags: flutter

```
#0      int._handleFormatError (dart:core-patch/integers_patch.dart:129:7)

#1      int.parse (dart:core-patch/integers_patch.dart:55:14)

#2      minSdk (package:flutter_launcher_icons/android.dart:309:18)

#3      createIconsFromConfig (package:flutter_launcher_icons/main.dart:94:47)

#4      createIconsFromArguments (package:flutter_launcher_icons/main.dart:60:7)

#5      main (file:///C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_launcher_icons-0.9.2/bin/main.dart:6:26)

#6      _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:295:32)

#7      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:192:12)
pub finished with exit code 255
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Not sure what the issue is, I assume you double checked the path to your icon? Maybe try running it with `dart pub run` instead of `flutter pub run` will change the result

Comment: [pub finished with exit code 255](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59902005/10157127) might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced similar issue . I resolved it by changing following properties in android/app/build.gradle

```
minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
```

**To**

```
minSdkVersion 26
targetSdkVersion 32
```